# Update Error de Sintaxis

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos dias, estoy intentando hacer un "Update" a dos tablas dentro de mi base de datos pero al hacerlo me marca un error y no soy capaz de encontrar el error, hasta donde entiendo la sintaxis de mi query esta bien. Pero aun asi phpmyadmin me lanza el error de que algo no esta bien con la sintaxis.

Aqui el Codigo:

```
UPDATE
    pm_t_bb
INNER JOIN pm_t_pt ON(pm_t_bb.OT = pm_t_pt.OT)
SET
    pm_t_bb.BB_1 = 'R' pm_t_bb.BB_2 = 'R' pm_t_bb.BB_3 = 'R' pm_t_bb.BB_4 = 'R' pm_t_bb.BB = '100' pm_t_bb.F_Up = Now() pm_t_pt.BB = '1.5'
WHERE
    pm_t_bb.OT = '1010176'
```

La una diferencia respecto a cuando funcionaban mis actualizaciones era que estaban en consultas separadas y por cuestiones de performance pues las uni.

Gracias de Antemano!

Saludos a todos!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y no, la sintaxis esta mal, no se puede hacer un update con un inner join, debe ser ese el error que te marca (y de paso, aclara cual es el error).

Comment: ^ Y te faltan algunas comas separando campos (todas para ser exacto)

Comment: Muchas gracias, es correcta la observación que me hacen, me faltan comas al final de cada linea dentro del SET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proba de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE
     A
SET
    pm_t_bb.BB_1 = 'R',
    pm_t_bb.BB_2 = 'R', 
    pm_t_bb.BB_3 = 'R', 
    pm_t_bb.BB_4 = 'R', 
    pm_t_bb.BB = '100', 
    pm_t_bb.F_Up = Now() ,
    pm_t_pt.BB = '1.5'

FROM pm_t_bb A
    INNER JOIN pm_t_pt B ON A.OT = B.OT

WHERE
    A.OT = '1010176'
```

Comment: update set from? esto anda en serio? es la primera vez que lo veo... tienes algun ejemplo o documentacion al respecto?

Comment: Si asi se realizan te paso un link de referencia http://ridersofthebit.net/2010/10/05/como-utilizar-join-en-sentencias-update-o-delete-mysql/

Comment: genial gracias por el link. Igual ahi explican que se escribe exactamente igual que como lo escribio OP.. mas alla de que a OP le falten las comas.. y en unsa segunda vista el problema puede ser eso...

Comment: Muchas gracias Hector Scesa. Tu observación arreglo mi problema. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Probá poniendo comas entre los valores:

```
UPDATE
pm_t_bb
INNER JOIN pm_t_pt ON(pm_t_bb.OT = pm_t_pt.OT)
SET
    pm_t_bb.BB_1 = 'R', pm_t_bb.BB_2 = 'R', pm_t_bb.BB_3 = 'R', 
    pm_t_bb.BB_4 = 'R', pm_t_bb.BB = '100', pm_t_bb.F_Up = Now(), pm_t_pt.BB = '1.5'
WHERE
    pm_t_bb.OT = '1010176'
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo la sintaxis de la página de MySQL para los UPDATE.

```
UPDATE tabla SET campo = valornuevo WHERE condición;
```

[MySQL UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)